# What is the best way to parameterize a task on Gradle?

Tags: gradle, parameters, task, parameter-passing

I need to create two different .properties files from two different .properties.dist if they don't exist, so I'm using a Copy task and I'm specifying the from and the into accordingly.

At the moment I had to create two different tasks, each of which is creating a file like this:

```
task copyAndRenameDialling(type: Copy){
    if(!file("./properties/dialling.properties").exists()){

        from './dist/dialling.properties.dist'
        into './properties/'
        rename{ String fileName ->
            fileName.replace('.dist','')
        }
    }
}

task copyAndRenameFiles(type: Copy){
    if(!file("./properties/file.properties").exists()){

        from './dist/files.properties.dist'
        into './properties/'
        rename{ String fileName ->
            fileName.replace('.dist','')
        }
    }
}


task copyAndRenameProperties {
    dependsOn << copyAndRenameDialling
    dependsOn << copyAndRenameFiles
}
```

and I run the task with gradle `copyAndRenameProperties`.
Is it possible to make the two Copy tasks parameterized based on the name of the file, so that I have only one generic copyAndRename?
If so, how can I pass the parameter to the task?

Comment: Do you really need those as separate tasks so that you can call them individually or is one task enough that copies the files that are absent in the target?

Comment: I don't need them as separate task, that's why I want to factorize it.
I'd like to know if I could do this using the same "task" pattern and using two different parameters, i.e. the names of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
task copyAndRenameProperties(type: Copy) {
    from 'dist'
    include '*.properties.dist'
    into 'properties'
    rename { it - ~/\.dist$/ }
    eachFile { if (file("properties/$it.name").file) it.exclude() }
}
```

or if you really only want those two specific files

```
task copyAndRenameProperties(type: Copy) {
    from 'dist/dialling.properties.dist'
    from 'dist/file.properties.dist'
    into 'properties'
    rename { it - ~/\.dist$/ }
    eachFile { if (file("properties/$it.name").file) it.exclude() }
}
```

or

```
task copyAndRenameProperties(type: Copy) {
    from 'dist'
    include 'dialling.properties.dist', 'file.properties.dist'
    into 'properties'
    rename { it - ~/\.dist$/ }
    eachFile { if (file("properties/$it.name").file) it.exclude() }
}
```

Comment: I really like the first one!
I have 2 questions:
- where is 'it' defined?
- what is the rename... statement for?

Comment: `rename { it - ~/\.dist$/ }` basically is a method call of method `rename` with the closure `{ it - ~/\.dist$/ }`. In a closure with one argument it is called `it` if you don't name it explicitly like in your original post. The rename statement is for the same thing as yours, mine is just a bit more compact, but it does the same.